# send the request id with XMLHttpRequest to the serverside

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Here I deployed the Get request with Id to pass from the client-side to the server-side to download excel file according to the Id.

**client-side js file**

```
$scope.getAUGFile = function () {

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                var params = JSON.stringify({ articleId: articleId });
                var url = RESOURCES.USERS_DOMAIN + '/AUGFile/excelDownload/'
                xhr.open("GET", url+"?"+params);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", getJwtToken());
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';

                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        saveAs(xhr.response, "mvvAUGExcelTemplate.xls");
                    }
                };

                xhr.send(null);
            };
```

**server-side js file(spring boot)**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/AUGFile/excelDownload/{articleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseWrapper excelGenerateAUG(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable Long articleId){

        try{
            fileService.downloadAUGFile(request,response,articleId);
            return ResponseWrapper.successWithMessage(messageSource.getMessage("success_code",null, Locale.ENGLISH));
        } catch (Exception e){
            lOG.error(">> Excel file Download error", e);
            return ResponseWrapper.failWithMessage(messageSource.getMessage("fail_code", null, Locale.ENGLISH));
        }
    }
```

When I execute the client-side function, In the serverside take the `articleId` value as **NULL**. How can I fix it? Any advice, help, pointers welcome!

Comment: Did you check on client-side, the value of **articleId**. You can console.log and check if you are getting some value.

Comment: you realise your request will be something like `/AUGFile/excelDownload/?{"articleID":123}` - does your server side handle that?

Comment: I think because of your url, In your server side you are expecting parameter after `/` -> `/AUGFile/excelDownload/{articleId}` and in javascript/angularjs you are calling api with parameter as `?` -> `url+"?"+params`

Answer (score 0):

first 
`console.log(articleId)`  inside your function  to see if its defined and accessible to xhr to send

& try this  this  instead  `xhr.open("GET", url+articleId);`

or try this 
 `xhr.open("GET", url+"?articleId="+articleId);`

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct way of this! It is working now.

**client-side js file**

```
$scope.getAUGFile = function () {

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                var url = RESOURCES.USERS_DOMAIN + "/AUGFile/excelDownload/"+articleId;
                xhr.open("GET", url);
                xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", getJwtToken());
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';

                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        saveAs(xhr.response, "mvvAUGExcelTemplate.xls");
                    }
                };

                xhr.send(null);
            };
```

**server-side js file**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/AUGFile/excelDownload/{articleId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseWrapper excelGenerateAUG(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@PathVariable("articleId") String articleId){

        try{
            fileService.downloadAUGFile(request,response,articleId);
            return ResponseWrapper.successWithMessage(messageSource.getMessage("success_code",null, Locale.ENGLISH));
        } catch (Exception e){
            lOG.error(">> Excel file Download error", e);
            return ResponseWrapper.failWithMessage(messageSource.getMessage("fail_code", null, Locale.ENGLISH));
        }
    }
```